# Android listview elements with clickable animated checkboxes

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have a listview whose items contain a few `TextView`s, and 7 custom `CheckBox`es. In my adapter class I have `ArrayList` that stores all the data for each element, including boolean array for each checkbox's state.

When I scroll the list down I use convertView to draw new element. For example, if the first item disappeared, its view will be used for drawing, let's say, 6'th item. I also use ViewHolder to store references to all the `View`s inside every visible `ListView`'s item.

Now, every checkbox has its onCheckedChangedListener, inside of which its new state is written into boolean array of according element of `ArrayList`. Like, we changed state of the 4'th checkbox of the 2'nd element of the `ListView`, so we need to find 2'nd element in `ArrayList` and changed 4'th value in its boolean array.

Except for changing boolean in `ArrayList`, when I change checkbox's state I also start an animation, and it's really important to start it only when I physically click on checkbox. But remember how I use disappeared item to draw new one? Since I'm reusing `convertView` I need to change its checkbox's states according to boolean array of the element that I'm trying to draw. For example, I'm drawing 6'th element of the `ListView` and use view of the first element for it. Let's say, the first element had state of its checkboxes like this:

`{true, true, true, true, true, false, false}`

and 6'th element should be displayed like this:

`{false, false, false, false, false, false, false}`

For the first 5 of them `onCheckedChanged()` will be invoked, which will trigger the animation. But as I said, I want to start animation only if I physically clicked the checkbox. I was going to use another callback, `onTouchEvent()` would be great, but it doesn't have boolean parameter that shows if checkbox is checked or not. Any ideas will be strongly appreciated.

EDIT 1 - my adapter:

```
public class AlarmsArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

ArrayList<AlarmClock> alarmClockArrayList;
private Context context;

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView time;
    TextView songTitle;
    TextView nextRingTime;
    CheckBox repeatCheckBox;
    RelativeLayout repeatPanel;
    WeekDayCheckBox[] days = new WeekDayCheckBox[AlarmClock.DAYS_IN_WEEK];
}

public AlarmsArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<AlarmClock> alarmClocks) {
    super(context, -1, alarmClocks);
    alarmClockArrayList = alarmClocks;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     ViewHolder holder;
    AlarmClock alarmClock = alarmClockArrayList.get(position);
    Log.d("ADAP", "position = " + position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alarm_clock_item, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alarmClockTime);
        holder.songTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alarmClockSong);
        holder.nextRingTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nextRindDay);
        holder.repeatCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.repeatCheckBox);

        holder.repeatPanel = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.repeatPanel);
        holder.days[0] = (WeekDayCheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.MO);
        holder.days[1] = (WeekDayCheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TU);
        holder.days[2] = (WeekDayCheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.WE);
        holder.days[3] = (WeekDayCheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TH);
        holder.days[4] = (WeekDayCheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.FR);
        holder.days[5] = (WeekDayCheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.SA);
        holder.days[6] = (WeekDayCheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.SU);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    setListeners(holder, alarmClock);
    holder.time.setText(alarmClock.time);
    holder.songTitle.setText(alarmClock.songTitle);
    holder.nextRingTime.setText("No data");

    holder.repeatCheckBox.setChecked(alarmClock.weekPanelIsVisible);

    for (int i = 0; i < AlarmClock.DAYS_IN_WEEK; i++)
        holder.days[i].setChecked(alarmClock.weekDaysState[i]);
    return convertView;
}

private void setListeners(final ViewHolder holder, final AlarmClock alarmClock) {
    holder.songTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    });

    holder.time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, TimePickerActivity.class);
            ((FragmentActivity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, MainActivity.TIME_PICK_REQUEST);
        }
    });

    holder.repeatCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (!isChecked) {
                holder.repeatPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                holder.repeatPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            alarmClock.weekPanelIsVisible = isChecked;
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < AlarmClock.DAYS_IN_WEEK; i++) {
        final int j = i;
        holder.days[j].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                holder.days[j].startAnimation();
                alarmClock.weekDaysState[j] = isChecked;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

AlarmClock:

```
public class AlarmClock {
public static final int DAYS_IN_WEEK = 7;
public static int id = 0;

public String time;
public String songTitle;
boolean weekPanelIsVisible;
boolean [] weekDaysState;

public AlarmClock (String time, String title, boolean weekPanelVisibility, boolean [] weekDaysState) {
    id++;
    this.time = time;
    songTitle = title;
    weekPanelIsVisible = weekPanelVisibility;
    this.weekDaysState = new boolean[DAYS_IN_WEEK];
    this.weekDaysState = weekDaysState.clone();

}
```

EDIT 2: I just changed `onCheckedChangedListener` to `onClickListener`, hoping that it will help, but somehow `onClick()` has been invoked even if I just scroll the listview, i don't understand why that's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I got it. I just was starting animation inside my custom checkbox class every time I draw it.